# How to open python in cmd with the 'python' command in stead of py -3

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10, startup, reinstall

It is a minor issue, but since I reinstalled python (3.6.3 on windows 10), it no longer starts using the `python` command in the command prompt. Instead I have to use the `py -3` command now.

The error:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Since it is probably the most common way to use python in commands on forums, it becomes quite annoying to change it every time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit your path to include the new directory

Comment: You are probably on Windows and have to append to the `path` environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, others have said -- you could just add the python directory containing the executable to the PATH... I just want to give this as an extra option.

This is a general solution for any type of program or executable you'd like to run with a custom name.

I created an "Aliases" folder in my account `C:\Users\{Your Account Name}\Aliases`.

In that folder, I keep useful .bat scripts.

Just make a script called "python" and, in that script, put the path of your python.exe.

So, for example, this would be your entire bat file (named `python.bat`):

```
@echo off
echo .
C:\Python36\python.exe
```

if you want to be able to add args to your command, do the same but replace the execution line with the follows:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6
```

That will give you the ability to add up to 6 arguments. This is helpful if you're doing python pip commands directly from the command line.

After you create this file, simply add the folder to your PATH variable 
(**Start** -> Type **Edit the Environment Variables for your account** -> *Click PATH* -> click **Edit** -> *Append the location of your "Aliases" folder to the PATH, using a semi-colon to separate it from the rest.* -> Click **OK** and **OK** once again.) From now on, you don't have to worry about the PATH variable, just add more bat files and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Set the PATH variable

1. Go to Control Panel/System and Security/System
2. Click on Advanced System Settings
3. Go to the Advanced Tab
4. Click the Environment Variables button at the bottom
5. In user/system variables section, edit the existing PATH variable with the appropriate python directories.

example

```
C:\Python3.6;C:\Python3.6\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python3.6\Scripts\
```

Comment: There's no reason in general to add the "site-packages" directory to `PATH`.

Comment: yeah, its just habit for me for some odd reason